# How to break up a string into smaller strings with multiple overlaps?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, nested, xhtml

I have a large body of text that needs to be highlighted at given offsets + lengths.

The provided string is:

```
By Lesley Wroughton WASHINGTON Feb 25 (Reuters) - As scientists warn that climate change will lead to stronger storms the World Bank is launching on Monday the first disaster insurance plan to offer emergency money to 18 Caribbean countries immediately after they are hit by hurricanes or earthquakes.
```

And my provided `ranges` are:

```
var ranges = [
  {offset: 53, length: 10, highlightClass: 'a'},
  {offset: 74, length: 14, highlightClass: 'b'},
  {offset: 10, length: 20, highlightClass: 'a'},
  {offset: 20, length: 14, highlightClass: 'b'},
  {offset: 24, length: 3, highlightClass: 'c'},
  {offset: 28, length: 2, highlightClass: 'd'},
];
```

Before continuing I'm sorting the provided ranges according to their offset, so the above would yield:

```
var ranges = [
  {offset: 10, length: 20, highlightClass: 'a'},
  {offset: 20, length: 14, highlightClass: 'b'},
  {offset: 24, length: 3, highlightClass: 'c'},
  {offset: 28, length: 2, highlightClass: 'd'},
  {offset: 53, length: 10, highlightClass: 'a'},
  {offset: 74, length: 14, highlightClass: 'b'},
];
```

What I need to do is to highlight the various ranges here with their appropriate class-names (of a piece of text overlapped by both classes `a` and `b` for example than the string will have both classes applied to it). What I have so far works pretty good if only one overlap occurs on a word, but with multiple overlaps, as with the word WASHINGTON in this case, my code breaks down as I only check for 'next range' rather than try and see all available ranges and whether they overlap my existing ones.

I do this check by simply seeing if the next range has an overlap with the current one, if it does, I create a new range and push it before the next one, modifying the current one's length and next one's offset.

Is there a better way to break-down the string into multiple ranges accommodating all ranges that might possibly overlap?

Comment: Is this about generating HTML or XML markup, so that strict nesting of the marked up ranges is a requirement?

Comment: I'm trying to highlight different parts of the next using `<span class="highlight highlightClass">` and accommodate overlapping sections.

Answer (score 1):

One brute-ish force way to produce the necessary markup **with well-formed nesting** would be:

1. Compute and store the end positions of each range (in your case `offset` + `length`)
2. Sort the ranges by their start position (as you've done)
3. Create an array (let's call it `character_classes`) of as many empty arrays as there are characters in the text.

   - Note: We'll use the outer array as a list and the inner arrays as stacks. In JavaScript, arrays are a fitting data structures for both, but feel free to choose other suitable types if you like to.
   - Each stack in `character_classes` will track all classes applicable to the corresponding character in the text (the character with the same position in the text as that stack's position in `character_classes`). It will have those classes *in the order they were applied* when reading the text from beginning to the end.
4. Loop over your ranges:

   - Push each range to those stacks in `character_classes` that correspond to the start position of the range or any character after that.
5. Create a new empty string `result`
6. Loop over the characters in the text:

   For each character (and for the position *after* the last character)

   - pop ranges from the stack corresponding to the character until all ranges ending there (see computation results form step 1) have been removed

     While doing so:

     - remember all popped ranges that **don't** end there, including their order
     - for each range you pop (whether ending there or not), append the markup ending the corresponding class to `result` **in the order** the respective ranges are popped
   - push the remembered ranges (those **not** ending here) back onto the stack, **in the reverse order in which they were popped**. (Thus, they end up in the original order, just without the ones that ended here.)

     While doing so:

     - append the markup starting the corresponding class to `result` in the order you're pushing the ranges onto the stack
   - append the character from the text to `result`
   - remove the ranges that ended here from the stacks of all following characters, keeping the other ranges on those stack in their current order.

When you're done, `result` should contain the correctly marked-up text.